# IOS 7 - In App Purchase Tutorial

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am following [this In App Purchase tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial) and I can see the product description and title I posted at my iTunesConnect IAP content. However, When I click on the `buyButton`  I get a `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xc)` error at:

```
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];//<-- This line course the error.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

Someone suggest me to do a check on the `_product` before and after `buyButton`, and it did turn out different:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
        NSLog(@"productsRequest: %@", _product);
        //NSLog(@"productsRequest: %@", _product.localizedTitle);
    } else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}

- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Product title: %@", _product);//<-- this give different result from productsRequest function.

}
```

From `-(void)productsRequest`, I get

```
productsRequest: <SKProduct: 0x17e8e3f0>
```

and from `- (IBAction)buyProduct`, I get

```
Product title: #<CGRegion 0x17e8e3f0 empty>
```

And sometime some random long result:

```
Product title: Length 11 (2 blocks, 1 used, block 0 is at 0)
 11 0x165ae790 {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.838794 0.39337 1 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x165ae010> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 1, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}";
}
```

Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please expand your answer with code, which sets your '_product' variable. Moreover, I think, you'll find an answer by yourself just by checking it's value right before crash (possibly '_product' is nil or something like that).

Comment: @AlexandrPaliy you are right in a way that the `_product` is different every time I test. Check the edit I just did.

Comment: I see something is wrong, but still I can't give you any good advice. Try to set breakpoint in both of your methods and check `_product` variable values: 1) after setting it in `-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response` ; 2) before trying to use it in `- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender` . By "check" I mean using `po _product` in your debugger console. And yes, I hope, that two methods are in the same class.

Comment: @AlexandrPaliy I did what you told and 1) is `<SKProduct: 0x16692cd0>` and 2) is `[no Objective-C description available]`. Hmm... This is strange. Yes the 2 methods are in the same class.

Comment: Check your code and find every place where you assign any value to `_product`. If your button is disabled until `SKProductsRequest` receives response (so it's impossible that `_product` is not initialized yet), than something corrupts your `_product` between that 2 methods.

Comment: Not sure is a good solution but I found a way to overcome the error. I just add `SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];` into `-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response`. Not sure it is right but at least it work.